# How to flash Meizu MX4 ubuntu edition with another channel?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, flash, meizu-mx4

I tried to flash my just received Meizu MX4 Ubuntu edition to the rc-proposed channel by using

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/meizu.en
```

but I got the `unable to enter into recovery` error.

Anyone to provide the recovery.img as for the BQ Phone?

Comment: I should add to anyone reading this, that enabling developer mode on your device makes things much easier. Flipping that switch instantly enabled me to push the updates over ADB/ubuntu-device-flash while the phone was still booted into the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Connect your phone to Ubuntu desktop

```
sudo apt-get install phablet-tools
```

Unlock phone (you need also developer mode on)

```
phablet-shell
```

Inside shell

```
sudo system-image-cli --switch ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/meizu.en
```

After automatic download and reboot you will have the new channel.
Be warned this channel is not for normal usage.

---

Update (2017-10):
As Canonical dropped development, one may consider switching to more recent build channel from UBports. Command example below. Run it on Ubuntu host where you have connected your Ubuntu phone.

```
ubuntu-device-flash --server=http://system-image.ubports.com touch --channel=15.04/rc
```

Comment: Any website which can explain all this plus some more depth?

Comment: Note that I had to add `--build 0` to the end of that command to force the upgrade to the other channel. Without it, the channel remained unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

works great, 
I am a linux noob, flashed android several years.
don't want to compromise your perfect solution just like to edit it(for noobs like me)

this is what I did:

- (ubuntu pc) Open terminal and plug in your phone(with developers mode on)and type: `wget http://people.canonical.com/~alextu/tangxi/recovery/recovery.img`
- (on phone) hold power and vol- until the phone reboots (no normal screen display)
- (pc) now type in terminal:`fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`

wait until it's finished

- (phone) hold *power* and *vol+* to boot in recovery (flash) mode
- (pc) type the following command and replace *xxxxx* for *stable* (stable) or *rc-proposed* (release-candidate): `ubuntu-device-flash touch --device arale --channel ubuntu-touch/xxxxx/meizu.en`

now just wait

Answer (score 0):

stable :

```
wget http://people.canonical.com/~alextu/tangxi/recovery/recovery.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
ubuntu-device-flash touch --device arale --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/meizu.en
```

release-candidate:

```
wget http://people.canonical.com/~alextu/tangxi/recovery/recovery.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
ubuntu-device-flash touch --device arale --channel ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/meizu.en
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got that far just do a factory reset on the phone, it will reboot using the recovery files you just copied.