# Meizu MX4 how to make full resolution pictures with camera app?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, display-resolution, camera, meizu-mx4

I bought a Meizu MX 4  phone with Ubuntu pre-installed and I love it. 
The only problem I encountered untill today: the camera is supposed to be a 20Mp camera, but I can't seem to find a way to make pictures with that resolution. I tried all possible combinations of setting (there are few) and I alway get a 3Mp photo. 
I have tried re-intalling the camera app, to no succes.

Answer (score 2):

On my Meizu MX4 pictures are of size 5120x2880 ≈ 15 Mpix - there is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/camera-app/+bug/1468341) related to the camera and size of the pictures in Ubuntu for phones.

You might want to [change the channel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645652/how-to-flash-meizu-mx4-ubuntu-edition-with-another-channel) to rc-proposed and check if that helps a bit. Otherwise we need to wait until this bug would be fixed.