# MX4 Pro Ubuntu Edition can't normal boot

Tags: ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

during the ubuntu OS update on my Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition I reboot the system after 5 minutes. During the update the system show only the little ubuntu logo.

Since this time the phone start only with the text `fastboot mode ...`. The command **fastboot continue** via USB-cable start the phone. The button over the USB-cable flash for 2 sec, the Meizu splash screen is shown for 4 sec and after that the screen is dark, that’s it. Only **adb** works, no **fastboot**.

#### What I try:

- fastboot erase recovery
- fastboot flash recovery *recovery.img*
- fastboot reboot

doesn't change any think. This phone hangs after reboot. Again the system starts only after **fastboot continue**.

I followed this instruction: [How to flash Meizu MX4 ubuntu edition with another channel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645652/how-to-flash-meizu-mx4-ubuntu-edition-with-another-channel). Nothing was changed :(

Has anybody a good idea how to start the phone in normal boot?
And has anybody a good idea to show ubuntu touch on the phone and not a *back* screen?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Has really nobody any idea?  :(

Answer (score 0):

Start your phone, connect it via usb to your ubuntu host, use ubuntu-device-flash touch --device arale --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/meizu.en 
reboot the phone, apply a factory reset, reboot.
Be aware, you are doing a factory reset.